# django filter depeding on character count of the related model's fields

Tags: django, django-models

I have two models such that

```
class Employer(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(null=False,blank=False,default="")

class JobTitle(models.Model):
    employer = models.ForeignKey(Employer,unique=False,null=False,default=0)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=1000,null=False,default="")
```

and I would like to get all employers whose jobtitle name is less than X chracters. How can I achive this in Django ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct code for this is

```
Employer.objects.filter(jobtitle__name__regex="^.{0,20}$")
```

This will select all the employers who have a job title name up to and including `20` characters long. Just replace the `20` with whatever number you need.

Note that if an Employer has multiple JobTitles whose name are less than 20 characters long, it will return that Employer in the list multiple times. If you don't want this to happen, you should add `distinct()` to the query as follows:

```
Employer.objects.filter(jobtitle__name__regex="^.{0,20}$").distinct()
```

You'll now only get the Employer back once, even if they have multiple short JobTitles.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
Employer.objects.filter(jobtitle__name__regex="^\W{0, X}$")
```

When you use regex, you can filter records from database with provided regular expression. In this case all records with name which contains 0 to X signs will be returned

Comment: Thanks but don't we write jobtitle in somewhere ? And what does that regex exactly meaning ?

Comment: oo yes, I made mistake, of course it should be jobtitle instead of employer_set